# POST to mongoDB from react component state failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, axios

When I click the submit button the onClick event is supposed to POST the data that is set in the states of the react page to the mongodb using Mongoose. From console.logs and inspecting it is failing in the controller at .create(req.body) and throws the error status 422 that i have set.

```
// onClick function 

postBookDB = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.title) {
      API.donateBook({
        isbn: this.state.isbn,
        title: this.state.title,
        subtitle: this.state.subtitle,
        author: this.state.author,
        desc: this.state.desc,
        book_image: this.state.book_image,
        pages: this.state.pages,
        condition: null,
        notes: null,
        user: null
      })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  };

// controller
create: function (req, res) {
console.log("in create function");
console.log(req.body);
db.Book
  .create(req.body)
  .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
  .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
},

// API.js

donateBook: function (bookData) {
console.log(bookData);
return axios.post("/api/books", bookData);
}
```

I am getting this error in the console: POST http://localhost:3000/api/books 422 (Unprocessable Entity).

I've been researching trying different things, had two TA's and my instructor take a look and we are stumped.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Do they seperated like front end (react side) and back end (express and mongo) ?

Comment: Yes separated app structure.

Comment: I deleted my irrelevant comment. I did some researches and thought maybe the problem lies in the `book_image` field name. According to [this](http://arkusnexus.com/2016/09/12/coding-guidelines-mongodb/?nabe=5802299602763776:1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F), you can't have `_` in the middle of names. So maybe try changing that field name into something else and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Can you open developer console and network section. And please send us request and response for /api/books

Comment: I tried renaming without the _, still getting the api error, thanks though.

Comment: @hurricane Thanks for pointing me to the network tab. I was getting a validation error on subtitle. For that specific book i was adding there was no subtitle from the google books api. I changed the model to validation: false and it now works.  I can now sleep and keep working on my project further tomorrow now. Thanks again.

Comment: @NateJahnke Well done :) you can delete the question i think.

Answer (score 0):

@hurricane Suggested I look at the network tab in the developer console and inspect the POST message. I was getting a Validation error for subtitle because I set it to true.

Make sure you change your validation on your fields in your model so if you are leaving that field blank it will not throw that error and fail to POST to the DB.